# Store specific elements from a list into a chosen vector in R

Tags: r

My data:   [List of characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUS2r.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUS2r.jpg
[image]

I want to store specific elements(eg "h","k") from each of the above subsets within the list m into separate vectors
Currently using the following code:

```
for (i in m[[1]][[1]]{if(i=="k"){t<-m[[1]][[1]][m[[1]][[1]]==i]}}
```

I can store specific elements in vector for 1 subset individually. I want to store elements from all subsets simultaneously.
Thanks

Comment: Could you add an expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Of All, let's replicate your data!

```
a <- list(c("g", "g", "h", "k", "k", "k", "l"))
b <- list(c("g", "h", "k", "k", "k", "l", "g"))
c <- list(c("g", "h", "h", "h", "k", "l", "h"))

m <- append(append(list(a), list(b)), list(c))

> m
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "g" "g" "h" "k" "k" "k" "l"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "g" "h" "k" "k" "k" "l" "g"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "g" "h" "h" "h" "k" "l" "h"
```

Now, to store the specified element from all subsets simultaneously, we can add one more loop on your code:

```
t <- list()

for (j in 1:length(m)) {


  for (i in m[[j]][[1]]){

    if(i == "k"){

      t[[j]]<-m[[j]][[1]][m[[j]][[1]]==i]

      }

  }

}
```

On above case, we select the "k" element and response was:

```
> t
[[1]]
[1] "k" "k" "k"

[[2]]
[1] "k" "k" "k"

[[3]]
[1] "k"
```

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark